# installing FLTK 1.3.2 on microsoft visual 2010

Tags: c++, fltk

I'm getting this linker error when I try to compile the hello world .cpp after installing the FLTK kit.If you notice the library names are from installation found in appendix D in the stroustrup book "programming principles and practice". The edition is 2012 but it seems that  FLTK  version is a bit different now, for instance the version the book recommends to down load is FLTK 1.1.(?), and 1.3.2 is the latest. I think the linker problem is inside my VC++ project under the project/properties/linker/input/additional dependencies tab I put (per appendix d)

```
fltk.lib 
wsock32.lib 
comctl32.lib 
fltkjpegd.lib 
fltkimagesd.lib
```

But the .lib files I copied from the fltk lib folder didn't have those names. They are named:

```
fltkzlibd
fltkpngd
fltkjpegd
fltkimagesd
fltkformsd
fltkgld
fltkd
```

Are these the .lib files to include in VC++ project under the project/properties/linker/input/additional dependencies tab ? If not, how else can I fix this mess?

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  test.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'fltk.lib wsock32.lib comctl32.lib fltkjpegd.lib fltkimagesd.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>  
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>  

int main(int argc, char **argv)   
{  
  Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(300,180);  
  Fl_Box *box = new Fl_Box(20,40,260,100,"Hello, World!");  
  box->box(FL_UP_BOX);  
  box->labelsize(36);  
  box->labelfont(FL_BOLD+FL_ITALIC);  
  box->labeltype(FL_SHADOW_LABEL);  
  window->end();  
  window->show(argc, argv);  
  return Fl::run();  
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with FLTK, so excuse me if this is an insult to your intelligence, but: do you download the compiled build or source code? Also, make sure the binaries are compiled as libraries and not DLLs or some other format.

Answer (score 0):

Include those lib files for the debug version.  The release versions don't have the trailing d.

For the linking, use ws2_32.lib instead of wsock32.lib.

When adding your additional dependencies, did you click on the ellipsis and then in the dialog enter all the library names on one line?  They need to be entered on separate lines.

Comment: that's awesome. As you suggested I put each lib file in a new line and swapped out the wsock32.lib, but fltk.lib wouldn't work, so I tried fltkd.lib and it worked. hmm..

Comment: Are you building the release or debug version?  Release version use fltk.lib, debug use fltkd.lib.  Don't bother with the Debug Cairo version.

Comment: This is my first experience with installing developer tool kits onto my compiler. I don't know. I'm just trying to do the exercises on graphics in chapter 12 in Stroustrup's: "programming, principles and practice using c++". what's the difference between the debug and release version?

Comment: There are lots of differences.  If you open the project Properties, have a look at optimization and code generation.  Basically debug may contain extra code to help with debugging, release is optimized.  Sometimes bugs only show themselves in the release version so the customer is given the debug version.